# What is the correct syntax to Verify a mock logger call in F#?

Tags: f#, moq

I'm unit testing an F# function that calls `ILogger.LogInformation`. I'm attempting to verify that the function made the call as expected. Here is the verify statement I have so far:

```ml
let mockLogger = Mock<ILogger<MyFunction>>()

// call function that uses ILogger.LogInformation.

mockLogger.Verify(fun x -> x.Log(
    LogLevel.Information,
    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
    It.IsAny(),
    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
    It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>()), Times.Once)
```

When I try this I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Void' cannot be used for constructor parameter of type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit' (Parameter 'a...

System.ArgumentException
Expression of type 'System.Void' cannot be used for constructor parameter of type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit' (Parameter 'arguments[0]')
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments, String methodParamName)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(ConstructorInfo constructor, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprToLinqInContext(ConvEnv env, FSharpExpr inp) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:line 616
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprToLinqInContext(ConvEnv env, FSharpExpr inp) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:line 599
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToLambdaExpression[T](FSharpExpr`1 e) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:line 698
```

The exception is thrown when it calls the Verify method. How can I change this to get past this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about Moq, but I think part of the problem here is that you need another pair of parentheses around your lambda to separate it from the `Times.Once` argument. Try something like this instead:

```ml
mockLogger.Verify(
    (fun x -> x.Log(
        LogLevel.Information,
        It.IsAny<EventId>(),
        It.IsAny(),
        It.IsAny<Exception>(),
        It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>())),
    Times.Once)
```

Without the extra parens, your lambda returns a tuple, so your code is currently calling this method:

```ml
Verify: expression: Expression<Action<'T>> -> unit
```

[image]

But I think you want to call this method instead:

```ml
Verify: expression: Expression<Action<'T>> * times: Times -> unit
```

[image]

Here's a simpler example that should make the difference clear:

```ml
Verify(fun x -> x, 1)     // call Verify with a single argument (a lambda that returns a tuple)
Verify((fun x -> x), 1)   // call Verify with two arguments (a lambda and the literal value 1)
```

Comment: Oh, I was sooooo close! That's all it was. Awesome. The additional explanation and simplified example were very helpful for me to understand why.